# Access the public folder when using node and Express?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have looked through stackoverflow and read the express documentation, I can't figure out why the app won't run when I implement "app.use(express.static());" does anyone know a fix?

```js
var express = require('express')();
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

//If i use this my app will not start
// app.use(express.static());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});


//Get input from front-end
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  
   // On input do something
   socket.on('directional in', function(unique_id, input, input1){
     // send info to index
      io.emit('directional out', unique_id, input, input1);
   });
});


server.listen(3000, function(){

   // Server is running
     console.log('listening on *:3000');

});
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initialising express correctly. The correct way would be as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

With this, you will be able to do

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

All together, a fully functional express app would look like this in its most basic form:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Let me know what happens.

Comment: Hey Marcos. Its a late reply, but thanks for the input. Your answer helped me find the root of the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: but, when i did that. I am getting this error `GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1436164951394-63 404 (Not Found)` from index.html